# Issue a command based on content of a continuous output stream

Tags: bash

This command here:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events \
  --device /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.0-platform-INT33D6:00-event \
  | grep SWITCH_TOGGLE
```

Returns in a continuos stream, listening for changes on a device, strings like these:

```
event7   SWITCH_TOGGLE     +2.65s   switch tablet-mode state 1
event7   SWITCH_TOGGLE     +4.62s   switch tablet-mode state 0
```

Thing is, when the state changes to 1 I want this command to be issued:

```
systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

While when the state is 0 I want this command to be issued:

```
systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

How can I put all together?

Andrew Vickers, I even tried to do this to see if anything was returned, but nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash

stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events --device /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.0-platform-INT33D6:00-event | grep SWITCH_TOGGLE |
while read string; do
  echo "$string";
done
```

Nothing was being echoed..

Comment: Try `while read string;do echo "$string";done < <(stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events)` without `--device`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to deal with stream input in bash: some recommendations.

- use `sed` instead of `grep`: lighter and quicker:
- use a dedicated *FD* for your command to free *STDIN*.

My sample:

```
DEVICE=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.0-platform-INT33D6:00-event

exec 6< <(
      exec stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events --device $DEVICE |
          sed -une /SWITCH_TOGGLE/p
)

while read -u 6 foo foo mtime action target foo state; do
  if [ "$action" = "switch" ] && [ "$target" = "tablet-mode" ] ;then
    case $state in
        0 ) systemctl stop  iio-sensor-proxy.service ;;
        1 ) systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy.service ;;
    esac
  fi
done
```

From there, you could use `read` on *`STDIN`* for some *interactivity*:

```
DEVICE=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.0-platform-INT33D6:00-event

exec 6< <(
      exec stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events --device $DEVICE |
          sed -une /SWITCH_TOGGLE/p
)
LIPIDS=($(ps ho pid,ppid | sed "s/ $!$//p;d"))

while :;do
  read -t 1 -u 6 foo foo mtime action target foo state &&
  if [ "$action" = "switch" ] && [ "$target" = "tablet-mode" ] ;then
    case $state in
        0 ) systemctl stop  iio-sensor-proxy.service ;;
        1 ) systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy.service ;;
    esac
  fi
  if read -t .001 -n 1 USERINPUT ;then
      case $USERINPUT in
          q ) exec 6<&- ; echo User quit.; kill ${LIPIDS[@]} ; break ;;
      esac
  fi
done
```

Comment: If this don't work, try command alone or try without `--device $DEVICE`

Comment: Thank you very much both for suggesting usage of SED and for solving the issue by separating the execution of the command from the while cycle to execute commands on top of the output. Now I understand a bit better how stdin stdbuf and stdout work. Thank you!

Comment: Add `q` for ***quit*** in interactive loop.

Comment: Only one thing: it works very well if I launch it from root after logging in as root or using su, but it fails by launching the script with sudo giving this error back:  
```/home/red/Documents/tablet_mode: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'```
```/home/red/Documents/tablet_mode: line 3: `exec 6< <('```

Comment: Ensure you are running [tag:bash], not [tag:sh]!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

stdbuf -oL -eL libinput debug-events \
    --device /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.0-platform-INT33D6:00-event |
  grep SWITCH_TOGGLE |
while read -a fields; do
  case ${fields[6]} in
    0) systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service;;
    1) systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy.service;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. It seems it doesn't store the string into fields :/

Comment: There was a typo in my script. The array name on line 7 should be `fields`, not `field`. I have corrected it.

Comment: I corrected it in the version I tried, but it didn't work well. The answer proposed by F. Hauri works. Based on his answer, I would suppose your while cycle doesn't get anything to read